# Как получить текущую дату?

Tags: javascript, jquery

в формате 05.12.2021
или 05.12.21

Comment: @Pavel Nazarian
cпасибо. можете написать в ответ - отмету решением

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
let today = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
console.log(today);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
    const date = new Date();
    const dd = String(date.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
    const mm = String(date.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
    const yyyy = date.getFullYear();
    
    const today = dd + '.' + mm + '.' + yyyy;
    document.write(today);
```